# Can't Make Table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, heroku

I recently made a postgresql database but for some reason I cannot make a table in it. I am fine whether I can create it from a php script or with terminal; but I have searched many places and can't find anything that works. I have done a bunch of work before in mysql but postgresql just happens to be giving me problems.

I know on my php file I am properly connected to my database and I have ran numerous versions of this script like (inserted after the pg_connect):

```
$tsk1 = pg_query("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `elb` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `_user` (`_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3");
```

and I have also tried

```
  $tsk1 = pg_query("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'elb' (
          'id' int(8),
          'user' varchar(128),
          'pass' varchar(128),
          'name' varchar(128),
         ");
```

I also tried this but got a 500 error. And I know I am connected because I tried just changing one character in my password and it returned 'Could not connect'.

```
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=hostname port=portnum dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error()); 

$sql = pg_query('CREATE TABLE "elb" (
  "id" int(8),
  "user" varchar(128),
  "pass" varchar(128),
  "name" varchar(128)
)');

?>
```

Comment: I try adding a table in my database; but for some reason when I run the script it runs successfully but the table is still not made.

Comment: This is pg version 9.2.1

Comment: Why do you need to use quotes?  All your table and column names are sane no need for them.

Comment: I tried with and without so I just thought I would post the ones with; I have tried over 10 different formats to this code but none worked. So I am not really sure what is causing this not to work.

Comment: When you say the table wasn't created what does that mean. Did you do a select * from elb?  What schema did you create it in?  Check the context.

Comment: select from information_schema.tables and see if your table name is in the table_name column. select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'XYZ';

Comment: At first I kept running a select * from elb script. But then I noticed on my database providers dev site they say how many tables I have even though they for some reason do not show the structure. So every time I run this script I check that page and it keeps saying 0 so I know I don't have an existing table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int(8)` doesn't make sense in PostgreSQL, where `int` is a 32-bit integer (aka `int4`) and `bigint` is a 64-bit integer (aka `int8`).

This would be easier for you to diagnose if you collected and reported the actual database error message (should be in the database log file) rather than simply saying "500 error".

Comment: So would you suggest my changing my int to bigint or the 8 to a 4; because in mysql this always worked fine but if this is a postgresql thing I can try to make that work. Also I am on my postgres.heroku main dev site and they do not give me the option to look up log files so I do not know how to acquire that information for you guys.

Comment: `bigint` or `int8` is equivalent to `int(8)`.

Comment: your client access library should allow you to catch errors and display them properly. I don't know the details for PHP offhand, although using the low-level pgsql functions directly probably isn't the best way.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is probably the only DBMS that uses backticks (`` ` ``) as name delimiters. So, if you are certain you are connecting to a PostgreSQL database, you need to remove all the backticks in your script.

Things like `ENGINE=...`, `DEFAULT CHARSET=...` and other options after the CREATE TABLE statement are also most likely MySQL-specific and should be removed.

If you need to delimit names in your queries, use double quotes (`"`):

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "elb" (
      "id" int(8),
      "user" varchar(128),
      ...
```

Comment: That was another version of the first things I tried running but for some reason; that gives me a "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)" even though I know the code looks proper and works with mysql. I just don't know why my postgresql database is not accepting it... is there some special conditions that must be had? I have not worked with heroku php-apps before I just build websites.

Comment: Well now my entire php file is above(I edited it in) but I just don't see the error.(I tried both with and without the last comma)

Comment: @DevonBernard: Sorry, I thought the problem was only in SQL, so I assumed you would know how to deal with nested quotation marks. Anyway, I think you have at least two options: 1) use single quotation marks to delimit the PHP string, that way you'll be able to use double quotes *in* the string without issues; 2) use double quotes around the PHP string, if that's the preferred style, but then use `\"` for double quotes inside the string. I'm not well versed in PHP, so here's a link where these things may be explained better: http://www.nusphere.com/php/data_structures_php_strings1.htm.

Comment: @AndriyM I tried using single quotes around the entire query to use it in my php script but it still does not work. Do you think this could possibly be a host problem and they are not letting me create a table from a user-end file? As stated earlier I am completely new to Heroku so I do not know their rules about this kind of stuff.

Comment: What @araqnid suggested in their answer may be the issue at this point. One last thought: the closing `;` may be required. It [doesn't seem to be required](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0a43a/1) by PostgreSQL itself, but I don't know about other potential middleware which you may have installed and which may be preliminarily parsing all the queries sent to the DB server and depending on there always being a `;`, so you could try that one if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 1):

The meta-problem you have is that you don't read the error messages coming back from the PostgreSQL server. You can't be productive when programming with PHP/PG if you don't solve that first.

You PHP environment probably has `display_errors` set to Off. This is recommended value for production. From php.ini:

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; It's recommended that errors be logged on production servers rather than
; having the errors sent to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors

display_errors = Off
```

Assuming you can't change that not being the server administrator, you should be able to set it dynamically to On in while you're developping, by adding at the beginning of your scripts:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

After that the PG errors should be displayed automatically on the page as they occur.

If writing production-quality code, you'd want to check the result of each `pg_query` call, and when `FALSE` use the [pg_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) function to get the error message and output it in a log or in the page depending on the context.